# ¿Cómo consultar los 12 meses anteriores a partir de una fecha?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo cierta informacion de las ventas de un comercial por cada clientes mes a mes,  existen mas clientes por el mismo comercial

```
 factura  Cliente comercial total  mes      ano 
 001      juan     Ana       15    enero    2022
 002      juan     Ana       12    Febrero  2022
 003      juan     Ana       15    Marzo    2022
 003      juan     Ana       15    abril    2022
 003      juan     Ana       15    Mayo     2022
 003      juan     Ana       15    junio    2022
 003      juan     Ana       15    julio    2022
 003      juan     Ana       15    Agosto   2022
 003      juan     Ana       15    Diciem   2021
 003      juan     Ana       15    Noviem   2021
 003      juan     Ana       15    Octobre  2021
 003      juan     Ana       15    Sept     2021
 003      juan     Ana       15    Agosto   2021
 003      juan     Ana       15    Julio    2021
```

necesito realizar un reporte que visualice a partir de una fecha que ingresa como parametro los ultimos 12 meses, por ejemplo:  si ingreso agosto 2022 me debe mostrar todos los registros solo hasta el 12 meses antes es decir hasta el agosto 2021, el año y el mes entran como parametros

```
SELECT 
Factura , Client ,comercial, SUM(TOTAL) AS TOTAL, MonthName, DIM_CALENDAR.Date

 FROM 

 DWH.SOM.FACT_INVOICES

 INNER JOIN DWH.DIM.DIM_CALENDAR    ON DWH.SOM.FACT_INVOICES.DIM_CALENDAR_INVOICE_ID = 
 DWH.DIM.DIM_CALENDAR.DateKey


 WHERE  Date  >= DATEADD(Year, 1, GETDATE()))

 GROUP BY  Factura, cliente, comercial , MonthName, DIM_CALENDAR.Date
```

alguna idea please

Comment: Pero.. cual es el problema?? a DATEADD le podes pasar valores negativos, y en ese caso resta... si le restas un año.. listo!

Comment: cuando ejecuto me muesta todo no me hace ningun filtro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema, si lo que buscas es que entre el mes completo, es que tienes que llegar al primer día del mes actual, para recién ahí calcular doce meses. Un truco es este:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112), 6) + '01')

(Sin nombre de columna)
-----------------------
2022-08-01
```

Y ahora lo puedes usar en el filtro:

```
WHERE  Date  >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, CONVERT(DATE, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112), 6) + '01'))
```

Toma nota que el `DATEADD` hace `-1 YEAR` para ir hacia el pasado

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta